# How to make a word Bold in a sentence in flutter Text Widget

Tags: android, flutter

I have a paragraph to be displayed on a page, But in that sentence, some words need to be bold

```
final aboutSectionPieceOfContent = """
We are a "Not for Profit" trust venture building Wellness on wheels to address the serious problem of open defecation which is a major health risk for all in developing countries.

We are on the mission of integrating technology with our social cause.
​
We are in the process of providing a holistic approach to social responsibility keeping health, sensitization, safety, and Eco-friendly solutions
""";
```

This will be used as `Text(aboutSectionPieceOfContent);`

But the problem is I want some words to be Bold for example in first para line 1,  `Not for Profit` must be bold

How do I get that
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You can use RichText.

```
RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: "We are a  ",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                text: "\"Not for Profit\" ",
                style: TextStyle(
                  // color: Colors.green,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                //recognizer: _longPressRecognizer,
              ),
              TextSpan(
                  text:
                      "trust venture building Wellness on wheels to address the serious problem of open defecation which is a major health risk for all in developing countries.We are on the mission of integrating technology with our social cause.We are in the process of providing a holistic approach to social responsibility keeping health, sensitization, safety, and Eco-friendly solutions"),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Flutter [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) widget